# Styling an included layout in Android

Tags: android, layout, background, include

I have two layouts that contain a functionally identical panel.  One requires a background with rounded bottom corners; one requires a background with all square corners.  In all other respects, the panels are to be exactly the same.

Is it possible to change the background of the included layout without surrounding it in a `<FrameLayout>` or other wrapper?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a wrapper layout just for the background and use the [include](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) for all the common widgets

first_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width=”match_parent”
    android:layout_height=”match_parent”
    android:background="<FIRST_BACKGROUND>">

    <include layout="@layout/main_layout"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

second_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width=”match_parent”
    android:layout_height=”match_parent”
    android:background="<SECOND_BACKGROUND>">

    <include layout="@layout/main_layout"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Where main_layout contains all the components that you want to reuse

Comment: So in short I *do* need the `<FrameLayout>`?

Comment: It can be any type of layout. Or you can try yourLayout.setBackgroundDrawable or yourLayout.setBackgroundResource methods if you want to do it programatically.

Comment: True :) I was hoping not to have an enclosing element if possible because I hear it slows down layout.  I have also heard <FrameLayout> is one of the quickest to lay out, hence I will probably use one.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, having the wrapper layout will create one more view in the hierarchy. What are you basing the background selection on?

Comment: It's just statically determined by the layout I'm using.  In both cases it's an element under a `<LinearLayout>`.  I'm now wrapping the included layout in a `<FrameLayout>`.